# I would like to horizontally align buttons and center them with css

Tags: html, css, button, alignment, center

I'm trying to align 4 buttons horizontally in the center top of the page with css. this is what I have

```css
button {
  background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
  border: 5px;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

whenever i do this, the buttons get align in the center but also vertically, they should be horizantaly. I already tried this:

display: inline-block;
instead of
display: block;

but then my buttons become aligned horizonatlly but not center on top of my page.

Comment: Can you also provide your html markup? Are you using `div` or `button` tag for your buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do that is with a `text alig` in the container, like this:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class='container'>
      <button>MyBtn1</button>
      <button>MyBtn1</button>
      <button>MyBtn1</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two options.  In both cases, you need to wrap the buttons in a `div`, `nav` or some other element.  Then, you can use `display: inline-block` or `display: flex` to lay them out.  The `inline-block` option is the traditional approach and takes less CSS.  If you are interested in your page scaling to all viewport sizes (i.e. responsive design) `flex` is the better option.

### display: inline-block

```css
button {
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
nav {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
  <button>Button 4</button>
</nav>
```

### display: flex

```css
button {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
  <button>Button 4</button>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't think you need `flex-direction: row` since `button` tag is an inline element.

Comment: @SahinErbay, thanks! `flex-direction` also defaults to `row`, so it is doubly unnecessary. I was just trying to flesh out the flex-box model a little in case it was unfamiliar.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve??

Place the buttons inside a container and apply `text-align:center` to it.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
  border: 5px;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*margin: auto;*/
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <button>MyBtn1</button>
  <button>MyBtn1</button>
  <button>MyBtn1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't programmend since a long time, helped me, thanks!